# Getting Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop of type `array` expected `object` in React

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

i'm currently getting this warning in the console

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `dataSet.headings` of type `array` supplied to `myComp`, expected `object`.

i have a variable `data`

```
let data = {
  headings: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
}
```

and have this in the react render function

```
<MyComp dataSet={data}></MyComp>
```

in `MyComp` component i have this `propTypes` declaration

```
MyComp.propTypes = {
  dataSet: PropTypes.objectOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      headings: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.string
      )
    })
  )
};
```

I'm not sure what i've done wrong here. Can anyone shed some light?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data set is actually much simpler than your `propTypes` definition is.

You don't need the `PropTypes.objectof` there.

Instead, do this:

```
MyComp.propTypes = {
  dataSet: PropTypes.shape({
    headings: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)
  })
};
```

Comment: This works! I must have over thought it. Thank you!

Comment: You were very much on the right track though :). All the best! Happy Coding :D

Comment: Hi, Barry! I don't have declared proptypes , but the problem is on . this is what i am doing (https://jsfiddle.net/swjm4qvf/) - its helping on android, but not on ios - are there tips what can i do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

`objectOf` is to indicate an object with property values of a specified type, i.e. all strings or numbers.

Your data, however, is just an object with one property, `headings`, with a value that is an array of strings.

```
MyComp.propTypes = {
  dataSet: PropTypes.shape({
    headings: PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.string
    )
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In tabs element pass props as shown below code (renderTabBar)

```js
const Health_record = (props) => {
 return (
          <Tabs renderTabBar={renderTabBar} >

              <Tab heading="tab1">
            
              </Tab>
                <Tab heading="tab1">

              </Tab>
          <Tabs>
      )    
}

const renderTabBar = (props) => {
    props.tabStyle = Object.create(props.tabStyle);
    return <ScrollableTab />;
};
```